# Only one result out of ten showing in table

Tags: php, mysql

The code below returns the 10 most recent entries to a MySQL database.  That's what I want, but I also want it to display the results in an HTML table.  Right now, only the most recent result is in a table, a one-row table.  The rest of the results are displayed in a jumble of text.  How could I get all of the results in a 10-row table?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT loginid, title, url, displayurl
                FROM submission ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

    $arr = array(); 
    echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["loginid"].'</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Take a look at the actual html produced, you'll see an early closure of the `<table>` following the the following rows without a true "home"; this seems due to the bad placement of the close brace for the while (not even shown in snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `}` for the `while` to be above the `echo "</table>";` line.

That way the loop repeats once for every row *and* the `echo "</table>";` line happens *after* all rows. Without that close bracket, the table gets closed after the first row, and then another row appears but *outside* a table, and then another close-table tag, etc.

(Marking this as community wiki because mjv really should have just made his comment an answer. ;))

Comment: @Dav  Thank you for the credit; you could/should have claimed the reps, however.  I tend to use comments, at least initially, with these very localized questions.  Maybe this comes from my ambivalence on these, where I'm both trying to help the OP, but also finding ways of improving SO by not "polluting" its content with these one-use type of questions/answers.